# How to rewrite Content-Type header for audio request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-headers

how can I rewrite Content-type header for mp3 requests from "audio/mpeg" to "audio/mp3"?

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)+\.mp3$ - [L,T=audio/mp3]
```

Or

```
<FilesMatch "(\.mp3)$">
  Header set Content-Type audio/mp3
</FilesMatch>
```

and it didn't work for me.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: `audio/mp3` isn't a valid MIME type.

Comment: that's ok, I just need to test something with soundmanager2 library